# Computer Wins Everytime in Rock Paper Scissor Game

Tags: kotlin

Hello so I have created a simple rock paper scissor game using Kotlin. But the computer seems to win everytime even though I had won technically. Please have a look at my code and help me. Thanks `package com.blinky.kotlinbasics

```
fun main() {
    val computerChoice = ""
    var playerChoice = ""
    println("Rock, Paper or Scissor? Enter your choice!")
    playerChoice = readln()

    val randomNumber = (1..3).random()
    if(randomNumber == 1){
    println("Rock")
}
else if(randomNumber == 2){
    println("Paper")
}
else if(randomNumber == 3){
    println("Scissor")
}

    val winner = when{
    playerChoice == computerChoice -> "Tie"
    playerChoice == "Rock" && computerChoice == "Scissor" -> "Player"
    playerChoice == "Paper" && computerChoice == "Rock" -> "Player"
    playerChoice == "Scissor" && computerChoice == "Paper" -> "Player"
    else -> "Computer"
}
if(winner == "Tie"){
    println("The game is a tie")
}
else{
    println(winner + " won!")
}
```

}
`

Comment: @Mat sorry I dont understand shouldnt it be an empty string?

Comment: You never set the variable `computerChoice` -- it's always set to `""` -- therefore, in the `when` block, you always end up in the `else` branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computers choice is never saved, it is only printed. So instead of only printing the computers choice, you might want to modify one part of your code to:

```
if(randomNumber == 1){
    println("Rock")
    computerChoice = "Rock"
}
else if(randomNumber == 2){
    println("Paper")
    computerChoice = "Paper"
}
else if(randomNumber == 3){
    println("Scissor")
    computerChoice = "Scissor"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fun main() {
val computerChoice = ""
var playerChoice = ""
println("Rock, Paper or Scissor? Enter your choice!")
playerChoice = readln()

val randomNumber = (1..3).random()
if(randomNumber == 1){
    println("Rock")
    computerChoice = "Rock"
}
else if(randomNumber == 2){
    println("Paper")
    computerChoice ="Paper"
}
else if(randomNumber == 3){
    println("Scissor")
    computerChoice = "Scissor"
}

val winner = when{
    playerChoice == computerChoice -> "Tie"
    playerChoice == "Rock" && computerChoice == "Scissor" -> "Player"
    playerChoice == "Paper" && computerChoice == "Rock" -> "Player"
    playerChoice == "Scissor" && computerChoice == "Paper" -> "Player"
    else -> "Computer"
}
if(winner == "Tie"){
    println("The game is a tie")
}
else{
    println(winner + " won!")
}
```

you did not give any value to computer choice. Therefor when ever game end the computer choice is "" which comes under else condition therefore computer always win.

Comment: Code-only answers are not good answers. Please explain how this code solves the problem